# What's bad about dork disk/pie plate?

Tags: safety, rear-wheel

Why is this part, supposedly a failsafe to protect the rear wheel in case of damage or poor adjustment of the rear derailleur, so often maligned? Are they ineffective, or do they cause some undesirable, unintended effects when not removed?

Looking down on the "dork disk" seems unnecessary, as it could actually serve a useful purpose, no?

Comment: They are unnecessary and only add mass, drag and waste. They age quickly and become brittle. On many bikes they are cracked and deteriorating.

Comment: @Michael please post answers as an answer not as a comment. Comments do not have the same up and downvoting features.

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael - I disagree.  Spoke protectors are often useful and rarely cause problems.